# Angular directive failing silently (directive rendered too soon?)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular app with a custom element directive (`<uber-table>`). `<uber-table>` is supposed to take a collection of objects, render them into a `<table>` and add some functionality (click row to toggle the underlying object as selected, search box for live filtering, action links on each row with customized click callback(s) for each object). I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7oJfSdk2wZuGnDj7aPAF?p=preview) with the relevant code. Please note that Plunker is giving an error about `map` (`Object [object Object] has no method 'map'`), but locally I am not getting any errors.

The post-link function's `element` parameter is not the `<uber-table>` element as I expected. Instead it is the template's `<div class="uber-table">` element. This is preventing me from extracting data from `<uber-table>`. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `map` issue is from not including jQuery in demo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rundown on some of the issues.

First main issue is you want existing content already within the `uber-table` markup to exist, as well as a new template. Unless told otherwise the existing content ( `columns`) in this case will be overwritten. In order to include existing content in a directive that has a template, you need to set `transclude:true` then identify within template where this existing content needs to be placed using `ng-transclude` on element that will be parent of the content.

Here's [demo with transclude fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/S759kdyN5HavxA2MPyeY?p=preview)

New problems arise now where you are trying to use jQuery to loop over `columns` and return angular `attrs` => `column.attrs` . This throws undefined error.

I haven't tried to unravel this enough to sort out the columns issues yet. They should likely be handled by directive of their own

UPDATE: here's [slightly revised error free version](http://plnkr.co/edit/vzEtlzVitLSqB5zz4M5j?p=preview) using jQuery to parse column count. I'm afraid am still confused a bit by structure of this. I don't see need to use jQuery to parse colunms, this could be converted to directive or pass column definitions into main directive from controller scope

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things and looking at the documentation again, I finally got it working. The solution was to put the `post-link` function inside the `compile` function. Also I had to update my isolated scope to use `=`, set `replace` to `true` and set `transclude` to `'element'`.

I [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7oJfSdk2wZuGnDj7aPAF) if anybody wants to see the changes. The Plunker version isn't working, but since it is working locally, I'm not going to spend too much time on it.